# What determines if light rays will be parallel to each other after refraction through a lens?

Tags: optics, visible-light, astronomy, lenses, telescopes

This is an example of a refracting telescope:

[image]

As you can see, when passing through the eyepiece (second lens), the rays are refracted parallel to each other.

Why are they refracted parallel relative to each other? What determines if light rays will be refracted parallel to each other and why?

Comment: can you make your question more clear  ? I couldn't understand your last two lines and what are you looking for ?

Comment: @Ankit I've removed the last 2 sentences, because it didn't add much to the original question